# How to fit an image in rightbarbuttonitem

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, rightbarbuttonitem

I've been trying to put a `hamburger` button (the three parallel lines) to the right of the `titleView` in the nav bar, but every time I do, the image I put in covers the entire nav bar and gets rid of the image I have in `titleView`.

If I select a default image in the storyboard editor it will appear on the right side of the nav bar without any problems, but as soon as I select the hamburger button in the storyboard editor I get the same problem as before. I've tried with multiple different images and I've changed up the code a little bit with no success. Is there a way to resize the image I'm using so it will fit in the nav bar properly or is there just something wrong with my code?

Here is my code from `viewController.swift` below:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))

    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    let titleImage = UIImage(named: "logowhitecircle")
    imageView.image = titleImage

    navigationItem.titleView = imageView

    let menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))

    menuButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    let menuImage = UIImage(named: "hamburgericon")
    menuButton.setImage(menuImage, for: .normal)

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuButton)
```

Comment: Do you have the `hamburgericon.png` with the `@2x` and `@3x` versions all in the correct size for a `UIBarButtonItem`? And why use a `UIButton`? Just use the `UIBarButtonItem` initializer that takes an image.

Comment: The problem is that you have not put any width and height autolayout constraints on your button.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set image size in the image assets like **3x = 84px, 2x=56px, 1x = 28px**,

[image]
see the apple document for more info: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/

```
let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "logowhitecircle"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(menuButtonTapped(_:)))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuBu
```

tton

Answer (score 0):

Try Using below code:

```
        let imageBurger = UIImage(named: "hamburgericon")!
        let btnLeftMenu = UIButton(type: .system)
        btnLeftMenu.bounds = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: imageBurger.size.width, height: imageBurger.size.height)
        btnLeftMenu.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

        btnLeftMenu.setImage(imageBurger, for: UIControl.State())
        btnLeftMenu.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnLeftMenu)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this module **FFBadgedBarButtonItem** it's easy to use module, here is the documenataion [Link](https://github.com/granoff/FFBadgedBarButtonItem)

Below is my code how to implement it!

```
let image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")

let finalImage = resizeImage(image: image!, newWidth: 30)

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = FFBadgedBarButtonItem(image: finalImage, target: self, action: #selector(rightButtonTouched))
```

And here is the calling function

```
@objc func rightButtonTouched() {
        // what event you need to perfom by clicking on this button
    }
```

You need to create **Bridging Header** to work with this Obj-C module.

: D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            //create a new button
            let button: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
            //set image for button
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "hamburgericon"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            //add function for button
            button.addTarget(self, action: "customButtonPressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            //set frame
            button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)

            let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
            //assign button to navigationbar
           self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
    }

    //This method will call when you press button.
    func customButtonPressed() {

            println("button pressed")
    }
}
```